# How to return data from BottomSheetDialogFragment to Parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, interface, fragment, bottom-sheet

I am populating a RecyclerView inside a bottomsheet and displaying the BottomSheet as a BottomSheetDialogFragment. WHen an item from the RecyclerView is clicked, i want to Auto fill a form using details from that item.

How do i pass a class(model) object containing the data from the BottomSheetDialogFragment to the Fragment where i instantiated the BottomSheetDialogFragment on. Here's my code

*Fragment i want to auto populate fields*

```
public class FormFragment extends Fragment implements onItemSelected {public class fetchSimilarContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String result, res, search;

    fetchSimilarContacts(String sear){
        search = sear;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        try {
            if (res.equals("200")){
                try {
                    // bring up bottom sheet
                    bottomSheetDialogFragment = new formBottomSheet();
                    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
                    bun.putParcelableArrayList("data", contItems);
                    bottomSheetDialogFragment.setArguments(bun);
                    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}}
```

I get the data and populate the RecyclerView using the asynctask function above. Here's the formBottomSheet class

```
public class formBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{

similarContactAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView rec;
ArrayList<hash> contItems;
View v;
onItemSelected itemSelected;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //contItems = new ArrayList<hash>();
    if(getArguments() != null){
        contItems = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data");
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);*/
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_bottomsheet_recyclerview, container, false);

    rec = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    itemSelected = (onItemSelected) getParentFragment();
    //contItems = new ArrayList<hash>();
    mAdapter = new similarContactAdapter(contItems, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new similarContactAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(hash hsh) {
            //after clicking on an item in the RecyclerView, i get the item's data here, how to i pass the data from here to the Form Fragment where i instantiated the bottom sheet fragment dialog?
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    rec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    rec.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rec.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
}

public interface onItemSelected {
    void SendHashItem(hash hsh);
}   }
```

after clicking on an item in the RecyclerView, i get the item's data here, how to i pass the data from here to the Form Fragment where i instantiated the BottomSheetFragmentDialog?

Here's my activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the status bar.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        //initialize
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewp);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        title = findViewById(R.id.title);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.transparent));

        setupTabIcons();

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                View tabView = tab.getCustomView();

                // get inflated children Views the icon and the label by their id
                TextView tab_label = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab);

                // change the label color, by getting the color resource value
                tab_label.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                // change the image Resource
                // i defined all icons in an array ordered in order of tabs appearances
                // call tab.getPosition() to get active tab index.
                tab_label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, tabIconsActive[tab.getPosition()], 0, 0);
                //"#4CAF50");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                View tabView = tab.getCustomView();

                // get inflated children Views the icon and the label by their id
                TextView tab_label = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab);

                // change the label color, by getting the color resource value
                tab_label.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));
                // change the image Resource
                // i defined all icons in an array ordered in order of tabs appearances
                // call tab.getPosition() to get active tab index.
                tab_label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, tabIcons[tab.getPosition()], 0, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, 0 , true);
                tabLayout.setSelected(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
        setToolbarTitle();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new VideoFragment(), "Video");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeSixtyFragment(), "360");
    adapter.addFragment(new FormFragment(), "Form");
    adapter.addFragment(new SettingsFragment(), "Settings");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cust_tab, null);
    tabThree.setText("Video");
    tabThree.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
    tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_video_red, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabThree);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cust_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText("360");
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_360_white, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cust_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("Form");
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_form_white, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabFive = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cust_tab, null);
    tabFive.setText("Settings");
    tabFive.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_settings_white, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFive);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your `FormFragment` and your `formBottomSheet` are fragments that live inside the same Activity instance.

Sometimes a Fragment will have "parent" or "child" Fragments, but that is not the case here because your `FormFragment` uses `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to show the bottom sheet, rather than `getChildFragmentManager()`. This is totally fine, but it's something to keep in mind.

What this means is that the best way for `formBottomSheet` to "talk to" `FormFragment` is to instead talk to the Activity and then have the Activity pass that along to `FormFragment`.

`formBottomSheet` -> `Activity` -> `FormFragment`

Talking to the Activity is pretty easy. You can just call `getActivity()` and cast it to whatever your Activity's class name is:

```
mAdapter = new similarContactAdapter(contItems, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new similarContactAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(hash hsh) {
        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
        activity.onHashItem(hsh);
    }
});
```

Inside your Activity, you can use the FragmentManager to get ahold of your `FormFragment` and then send the message along to it. This relies on the `FormFragment` either having an `id` (if you set an `android:id` attribute on it in XML or if you used `replace(R.id.some_id, ...)` then you can use the id) or a `tag` (if you set an `android:tag` attribute on it in XML or if you used `replace(..., "TAG")` then you can use the tag).

```
public void onHashItem(hash hsh) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // use only one of the two following lines
    FormFragment fragment = (FormFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.some_id); // if using id
    FormFragment fragment = (FormFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("TAG"); // if using tag

    fragment.onHashItem(hsh);
}
```

Finally, you can create the `onHashItem()` method in your `FormFragment`:

```
public void onHashItem(hash hsh) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I get null reference while trying to get FormFragment via id or tag. In my activity, i used view pager, so i tried getting the current fragment but my list of fragments returned zero i think because the BottomSheetDialogFragment is active

Comment: This is a long route. He can have an interface implemented in the fragment that needed it without any need of referencing the Host Activity.